# Date difference in Amazon Aurora postgres and hsql

Tags: hsqldb, datediff, amazon-aurora

I am looking for some common approach for taking date difference for hsql and aurora postgres. I know that direct date difference is supported for aurora postgres i.e `date1 - date2 > 2` works for it but this is not supported in hsql. `DATEDIFF('day' , TO_CHAR(sysdate,'yyyy-MM-dd'),TO_CHAR(mysample_date,'yyyy-MM-dd'))` is supported in hsql but not in aurora postgres.

Is there any common approach for the same?

Any lead will be appreciated.

Comment: The code you have shown is not valid for Postgres. There is no datediff or `sysdate` in Postgres. And "datediff" on two strings make no sense either (and even if there was a datediff in Postgres I'm pretty sure Postgres would reject passing two strings). So which DBMS are you really using?

Comment: Hello, I know that sysdate will not work in postgres. Let me explain my question. My table has two date fields let's say date1, date2. Now I want to retrieve all the rows where date1 - date2 > 5. So I wrote that select * from my_table where date1 - date2 > 5. This went well for postgres. Now same didn't work for HSQLDb. So I changed query to select * from my_tabpe where DATEDIFF('day',TO_CHAR(date1,'YYYY-MM-DD'),TO_CHAR(date2,'YYYY-MM-DD')) > 5. I want common approach  that works for both of the dbs.

Comment: `date1 - date2` works just fine in HSQLDB. And `datediff` in HSQLDB accepts `DATE` values, not strings.

Comment: `date1 - date2` works with hsqldb but it is not giving me any result whereas I am able to get an exact result by datediff. My team is using HSQL 2.3.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use a more recent version of HSQLDB. The latest versions treat the non-standard `date1 - date2 > 5` as `date1 - data2 > 5 DAY` (Standard syntax), while some earlier versions didn't treat it as a DAY difference.